# Connected callback firing for component that does not have a parent element

Tags: javascript, web-component, native-web-component

I have a web component, thats quite large and complicated, but here is the part that is giving me an issue.
About once in every 20 times I reload the page I get this error (within connected call back, it does not have a parent element):

```
wc-reorder-wrapper.min.js:153 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')
    at Component.setupDragEvents (wc-reorder-wrapper.min.js:153:28)
```

The error is being generated in the `connectedCallback`:

```js
    connectedCallback() {
        this.setupDragEvents()
    }
    setupDragEvents() {
        this.parentElement.addEventListener('dragover', this.parentDragoverHandler.bind(this));
    }
```

`this` does not have a `parentElement`, how can it be connected then?
To quote [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_components/Using_custom_elements)

> Inside the method connectedCallback, we define all the functionality the element will have when the element is connected to the DOM

If I set a breakpoint when there is no parent, and I `console.log(this)` then right click on it and select `Reveal in elements panel` it says:
`Node cannot be found in the current page.` ... which confirms it is not connected to the DOM, despite is connected callback being fired.

Using Chrome 113

Why does the element not have a parent element in `connectedCallback`, what is `connectedCallback` for then?

Comment: And when you change ``parentElement`` to ``parentNode``?

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman `parentNode` is `null`. and `this.isConnected` is `false`. For now my hack is just to retry ever 100ms, and it has a parent on the first try everytime I have tested. However it tells me my understanding is wrong.

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? I'm unable to reproduce this issue, and my attempts surely don't reflect your actual setup properly.

Comment: Sounds like you are adding DOM elements async. Show us the cause not the effect.